# I keep getting this error...?

Tags: api, syntax-error, python-requests, pprint

I'm trying to use an API for my Advanced Coding course, and no matter what I do, I always get this error. How can I... er... not get the error? Thanks in advance.

ETA: I'm using IDLE 3.4, I believe.

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import encodings.idna
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London')
pprint(r.json())
```

Now I'm getting an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lilyevans/APIproject.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are entering each line of the code on a new line? Which IDLE are you using?

Comment: I'm using IDLE 3.4, I believe.

Comment: and how are you running the code? --- Is it by hitting F5?
The reason I am asking this is because the bug is not in the code - it works perfect for me. But the bug is in the way you are running the code

Comment: I just press enter. To add new lines, I've been hitting shift-enter. I should also probably mention I'm on a Mac.

Comment: could you try writing the code in the IDLE save the file and then run it using F5? and tell me what happens? Or instead of Shift enter - could you please hit enter to move to next line?

Comment: I got a different error, this time:
    


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lilyevans/APIproject.py", line 4, in <module>
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: What is the error? is it - ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: OK - let me update my answer, save that file as it is and then run using F5. The reason you are getting these errors is because you are using Shift+Enter I guess. One sec posting an answer

Comment: I didn't use shift+enter this time, but still got the same error. Now it says that ['module' object has no attribute 'get'].

Comment: Were you able to execute it this time? If not Can you please paste your code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell, you can't execute more than one statement at a time:

```
>>> x = 5
y = 6
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
You need to execute them one by one:

>>> x = 5
>>> y = 6
>>>
```

When you see multiple statements are being declared, that means you're seeing a script, which will be executed later. But in the interactive interpreter, you can't do more than one statement at a time.

Try running this code. Make sure that lines are separated by enter and not shift enter

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests
import encodings.idna
r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London')
pprint(r.json())


Out[]:

{u'base': u'cmc stations',
 u'clouds': {u'all': 0},
 u'cod': 200,
 u'coord': {u'lat': 51.51, u'lon': -0.13},
 u'dt': 1415047029,
 u'id': 2643743,
 u'main': {u'humidity': 87,
           u'pressure': 989,
           u'temp': 279.78,
           u'temp_max': 281.15,
           u'temp_min': 278.15},
 u'name': u'London',
 u'sys': {u'country': u'GB',
          u'id': 5091,
          u'message': 0.0299,
          u'sunrise': 1414997905,
          u'sunset': 1415032183,
          u'type': 1},
 u'weather': [{u'description': u'Sky is Clear',
               u'icon': u'01n',
               u'id': 800,
               u'main': u'Clear'}],
 u'wind': {u'deg': 230, u'speed': 2.1, u'var_beg': 190, u'var_end': 260}}
```